# in my server, getting exception "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake"

Tags: java, ssl, https, openssl, jmeter

i am sending Http POST request to one server from my system. Its giving "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake" Exception.Even i am having valid certificate in my system.i tried with other system. Its working fine without any issues.how do we find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: You should add code that you have tried and complete trace.

Comment: How do you issue your POST request?

Comment: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
 ... 22 more

Comment: i am sending https request through jmeter

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is a mismatch between SSL protocol implementation JMeter and your server are using. I would suggest playing with the following properties:

```
https.default.protocol
https.socket.protocols
```

Like try adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
https.default.protocol=SSLv3
```

You can use [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) or sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to check what protocol is being used under the hood for successful and not-successful connections and what are the differences.

References:

- [Jmeter (Script) Monitors fail with the error "Remote host closed connection during handshake."](https://support.ca.com/us/knowledge-base-articles.TEC1265741.html)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for response.i have verified with the above options. Its not working